# What are some pros and cons for making a matrix with arrays vs vectors?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have been doing some research and cannot figure out which method/approach would be better and for what reasons. I want to create a simple empty matrix with a given length.

```cpp
int n = 5;
int m[1...n][1...n];
int s[1...n-1][2...n];
```

I am not sure if it would be best to do this with vectors or arrays. Can the answers also include a code snippet?

NOTE: The above code snippet works and compiles in `gcc -std=c++11`, but with actual values in replace of the `1...n` stuff

Comment: That code as given does not compile with `gcc -std=c++11`.   The decimal points trigger errors.    How about you explain in words what you are trying to achieve, rather than providing non-compileable code and claiming it works?   At present, your question is unclear.   What do you mean by a "simple empty array"?

Comment: I was saying in my `NOTE` that if you replace the `1...n` with like `5` then it compiles , but you need to replace it for all the blocks. I was using those numbers to represent a matrix in my question

Comment: In that case, your code is invalid C++.   gcc supports VLAs (a C99 feature) as a non-standard extension to C++.    Even with that clarification, your question remains unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays, like vectors, can store arbitrary objects except references(there are no type of reference in arrays and vectors)

Compared with vector, arrays has the following shortcomings:

1. The dimension of an array must be a constant expression, that is, it must be given at initialization. And will be not change in the whole process of running the program.
2. Arrays are not allowed to copy and assign, that is, the contents of arrays cannot be copied to other arrays as their initial values, but vectors can.
3. The process of using arrays is easy to go into array crossing, but vectors can use more mechanisms to control, such as iterators.